# Excel/VBA: Cannot get Variant/Boolean to return (should be trivial)

Tags: vba, excel, return

I cannot get this function to return my values to the output column in excel:

To overcome some intense lookup tables and speed up computation, I am using a pivot table with slicers to output row numbers from filtering. These rows then need to be converted into a column of true/false cells for a large table from which I then want to perform more calculations. To avoid lookups or matching I simply need to step through the list of rows and turn those cells to "true" in the output vector.

```
Function IncludedinSlicer(input_range As Variant) As Variant

Dim n As Long, j As Long, r As Long
n = input_range.Height ' Height of the column of reference values
' every row in the input_range contains a row number which in the output should be TRUE
' all other rows should be false

Dim output_range As Variant
ReDim output_range(1 To 300000)
' This covers the maximum number of rows

' Initialise all rows to FALSE
For j = 1 To 300000
    output_range(j) = False
Next j

' Set only those rows listed in the reference to TRUE
For j = 1 To n
    r = input_range(j).Value
    If r = 0 Then ' If r=0 then we are beyond the end of the reference table and have captured some blank rows
        Exit For ' Exit, to avoid outside-of-array errors
    Else
        output_range(r) = True
    End If
    'End If
Next j

' Return results to Excel
' THIS LAST BIT DOES NOT RETURN VALUES TO EXCEL
IncludedinSlicer = output_range
End Function
```

I know this should be trivial but somehow it has vexed me for literally hours. Please help! Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Found the issue!

First, thank you for pointing out the difference between Height and Rows.Count as I was not aware of this.

Unfortunately, that still left me with the same error in the final cell output (#Value). Luckily in the meantime I tried processing this via Matlab instead and when passing back the results I got the same error. This allowed me to narrow down the problem and I tracked the error to ... (drum roll) ... VBA's 2^16 limit for array size. 
My table has close to 2^18 rows so this causes the error.

Comment: Does your code error (if so what) or just return an unexpected result?

Answer (score 1):

`input_range.Height` refers to the literal height in pixels of the range. Try instead `input_range.Rows.Count` to get the number of rows in the range.

Answer (score 0):

For your function, you should be passing in (and potentially returning) a Range type instead of the ambiguous Variant type.

This will give you direct access to all of the properties of the Range type (i.e. Rows, Columns, Cells) and would probably make it easier to catch your issue that bobajob pointed out.